# Chrome & Edge don't recognize javascript changing textcolor of my buttons and textarea

Tags: javascript, firefox

To begin with I'm still a beginner in terms of web development.
The full source code can be found here: https://codepen.io/tommie-olislagers/full/NMrVKd

The code I specifically want working in Edge and Chrome is for example:

```js
var textcolor = document.getElementById('textcolor');
    textcolor.style.background = 'black';
    var textcolor2 = document.getElementById('textcolor');
    textcolor.style.color = 'white';
```

```html
<textarea id="textcolor"></textarea>
```

Where  textcolor = the textarea named by ID.
To clarify this WORKS but only in **Firefox** and not in *Edge* or *Chrome*.

Edit:
Here are two screenshots comparing Chrome vs Firefox.
Chrome: 
https://gyazo.com/72e144a466dcd740b7fb403285b18194
Firefox: 
https://gyazo.com/e6f17558fbbac7082e1521bce9c70202

Comment: Always check the console for errors. Thats javascript 101... `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined - pen.js:57 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console, it says you have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined -
>   pen.js:57

This is because at line 57 you have

```
var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
```

You'll notice that you set your variable name to `buttoncolor` but then accidentally used your `id` of `btntest3` as the target on the second line.

To fix it, use your correct variable. Change:

```
btntest3.style.background = 'black';
```

to

```
buttoncolor.style.background = 'black';
```

Though I'd change it to `var button_bg_color`.

You did this for the next set too so it's the same procedure.

```
 var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
  btntest3.style.color = 'limegreen';
```

to

```
var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
  buttoncolor.style.color = 'limegreen';
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it! I've only began with javascript yesterday so excuse my messy code and beginner mistakes :)

Comment: You're doing well - keep going!

Comment: On your advice, I changed all variable name's in line with their functions. I hope this makes the code seem a lot more clear.

Comment: @TommieOlislagers Yeah straight-forward names always makes things clearer and easier

Answer (score 0):

After i checked your codepen you need some cleaning in your code,

but what caused your issue is

```
 var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
 btntest3.style.background = 'black';
 var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
  btntest3.style.color = 'limegreen';
```

remove this from your code wherever it exists and your code will work,

Always check you console log for errors.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I've cleaned my code, I hope its more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because chrome and IE, stops code execution when an error is found..  in your code the

```
 var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
```

doesn't exists.. hence the

```
  btntest3.style.background = '' ;
```

will throw an error and your code will stop executing...

- To solve it you can delete those lines...
- Add the btntest3 element.
- Or wrap those line in a try {} block...

Answer (score 0):

```
 var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
 btntest3.style.background = 'black';
 var buttoncolor = document.getElementById('btntest3');
 btntest3.style.color = 'limegreen';
```

become

```
 var btntest3 = document.getElementById('btntest3');
 btntest3.style.background = '';
 btntest3.style.color = '';
```